# Getting 'Could not find configuration for port' Error starting N|Solid Proxy

Tags: node.js, nsolid

I'm getting the following error trying to start the N|Solid proxy

```
Daves-MBP:proxy-3.2.2 davblak$ npm start
> nsolid-proxy@3.2.2 start /Users/davblak/proxy-3.2.2
> nsolid proxy.js

/Users/davblak/proxy-3.2.2/proxy.js:9
 throw new Error("Could not find configuration for port")


Error: Could not find configuration for port
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/davblak/proxy-3.2.2/proxy.js:9:9)
  at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
  at startup (node.js:149:18)
  at node.js:985:3
```

I do have the etcd service running - any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `proxy-3.2.2` folder you need to have a `.nsolid-proxyrc` file with configuration options for your proxy, can you confirm if the file is in there?, if not this file should look like:

```
{
  "registry": "localhost:4001",
  "port": 9000,
  "denied": [],
  "broadcast_approved": [
    "ping",
    "process_stats",
    "system_stats",
    "system_info",
    "info",
    "versions",
    "startup_times"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, that is the issue.  I think I realized how this happened.  After downloading the files I went into the directory and copy/pasted the files via Finder.  As Finder doesn't by default show `.` files I didn't copy the `.nsolid-proxyrc` file.

I blew away my directories and tried again; this time I copied the entire directory at the folder level.  Using ls -al I now see the `.nsolid-proxyrc` file in there and the proxy works.  Thanks for all the help!